# Conversion from exponential to cosine

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-analysis, exponential-function

I'm trying to understand the following expansion. The question was

> Show that if $Y(t) = X(t+a) - X(t-a)$ and $X(t)$ is WSS, then
>   $$S_Y(\omega) = 4S_X(\omega)sin^2a\omega$$

The solution is

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
        S_Y(\tau) &= 2S_X(\omega) - e^{j2\omega a}S_X(\omega) - e^{-j2\omega a}S_X(\omega)     \\
               &= [2 - e^{-j2\omega a} - e^{j2\omega a})S_X(\omega) \\
               &= [2 - 2cos(2a\omega)]S_X(\omega) \\
               &=4S_X(\omega)sin^2a\omega,
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

I don't understand how the exponential expression is converted to the cosine expression. Is it because of any identity that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using $j$ for the imaginary unit, which is more commonly written as $i$ by English-speaking mathematicians (although electronics engineers like to use $j$, because they use $i$ for current).

The identity you seem to be unaware of is known as [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula):

$$e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x$$

FWIW, that formula is valid for complex $x$ as well as real $x$.

Substitution of $-x$ gives:

$$\begin{align}
e^{-ix} & = \cos (-x) + i \sin (-x)\\
& = \cos x - i \sin x\\
\end{align}$$

Thus,

$$e^{ix} + e^{-ix}  = 2\cos x$$

and
$$e^{ix} - e^{-ix} = 2i\sin x$$

Answer (score 1):

It relies on the fact that (using your notation with "$j$" for what is usually written as "$i$")$$e^{jt}=\cos t + j\sin t$$
From this it follows that $$e^{-jt}=\cos t - j\sin t$$ so that
$$\cos t = \frac12(e^{jt}+e^{-jt})$$